# The value of TextBox cannot be obtained and an error occurs

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I wrote the following code.

This is just the code to get the value from the textbox and print it.

But this doesn't work.

When I run this code, blender crashes.

What's wrong with this code?

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "test addon",
    "author": "taichi suzuki",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "test addon",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "test"
}

class QueryProps_query(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    query: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="aaa")

class TestAddon_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    blidname = "TestAddon_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "TestAddon Panel"
    bl_category = "TestAddon"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        props_query = bpy.context.scene.QueryProps_query
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="test textbox")
        row.prop(props_query, "query", text="")
        
        vis_box = layout.box()
        
        vis_box.operator(TestAddon_OT_Operator.bl_idname,text ='modal start')

class TestAddon_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_testaddon_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal testaddon Operator"
    _timer = None
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return{'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type=='TIMER':
            print(self.query)

        return{'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager

        if TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer is None:
            TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1.00/60.00, window=context.window)
            wm.modal_handler_add(self)
            print(self.query)
        
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer = None

classes = (QueryProps_query,TestAddon_PT_Panel,TestAddon_OT_Operator)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.QueryProps_query = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=QueryProps_query)
    
def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
        
    del(bpy.types.Scene.QueryProps_query)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a member named `query` of your operator on lines 53 et 63, but it doesn't exist. Instead you want to access the property group you created in your `register` method : `context.scene.QueryProps_query.query`.

Side note : Don't use `bpy.context` in an operator, because it is not always the right context. (L.28) Use the provided `context` parameter instead.

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "test addon",
    "author": "taichi suzuki",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3DView",
    "description": "test addon",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "test"
}

class QueryProps_query(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    query: bpy.props.StringProperty(default="aaa")

class TestAddon_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    blidname = "TestAddon_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "TestAddon Panel"
    bl_category = "TestAddon"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        props_query = context.scene.QueryProps_query
        layout = self.layout
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="test textbox")
        row.prop(props_query, "query", text="")
        
        vis_box = layout.box()
        
        vis_box.operator(TestAddon_OT_Operator.bl_idname,text ='modal start')

class TestAddon_OT_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_testaddon_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal testaddon Operator"
    _timer = None
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return{'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type=='TIMER':
            print(context.scene.QueryProps_query.query)

        return{'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager

        if TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer is None:
            TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer = wm.event_timer_add(1.00/60.00, window=context.window)
            wm.modal_handler_add(self)
            print(context.scene.QueryProps_query.query)
        
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        TestAddon_OT_Operator._timer = None

classes = (QueryProps_query,TestAddon_PT_Panel,TestAddon_OT_Operator)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.QueryProps_query = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=QueryProps_query)
    
def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in classes:
        unregister_class(cls)
        
    del(bpy.types.Scene.QueryProps_query)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```